# What is the official name/type of pattern?

Tags: texture, style-identification

What is this texture or fine artwork called/named? The poor graphic is a screenshot from a 70's styled movie? Geometric surrealism doesn't pull Google images, but is best guess.
[image: surreal geometric?]

Comment: If it is a 70's style it could be close to the "Late modern era". For me I will call it "modern art" abstract pattern

Comment: Could you please provide some other pieces in the same style, perhaps of a little higher quality?

Comment: @ZachSaucier I would if I could. Screenshot from ipad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Abstract Cubism

Karel mentions Geometric abstraction, which is close, but that tends to be flatter and simpler of composition, and have a more repetitive pattern.

This image is much more chaotic of composition, it's hard to find an actual pattern. It also shows different shades on relatively simple individual shapes, implying depth. Both Cubism and Futurism use this treatment of form, but they're generally more figurative:

[image][image]

Both these have fairly recognizable elements; a town and several ships. They're abstract**ed**, but not quite abstract.